# Will three barrels achieve hydrostatic equilibrium?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, flow

I have two barrels, each connected to the other by one hose along the bottom and fed by a household hose.
The left is the supply barrel for my irrigation system, the right, a backup (see below for clarity).
[image]

**If I add one additional barrel on the left, and connect said barrel to the supply barrel in the same manner as the barrel on the right, will the three still achieve hydrostatic equilibrium?**

I believe so, because the atmospheric pressure will still be the same on each barrel, and likewise, the mass of the water (given consistent temperature, unobstructed flow between the barrels, etc.), but I need to be sure.

Thanks to all!!

Answer (score 1):

If the barrels are connected at the bottom and vented at the top, the height at the surface of the water will be the same in each barrel. The size of the connecting hose may limit the rate at which they come to equilibrium.  If one of the barrels is sealed, the pressure of compressed air inside will limit the amount of water which enters.